# how to include php validation functions from another php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

Hello im new to web designing,i create one form to give statecode and statename. validation for this form in php and the validation done in another file.i dont know how to include the validation.please help me to validate and after to store in database.here i will attach all the files please help me friends.

```js
function stateAjaxsubmit()
{  
    var statename = document.forms["addstate"]["statename"].value;
    var statecode = document.forms["addstate"]["statecode"].value;
  
    var valueJson = {
        "State_Code": statecode,
        "State_Name": statename
    };
    
    console.log("Input");
    console.log(valueJson);
  
     $.ajax(
  { 
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,      
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url : "tocheck.php",
  type: "POST",
  data :JSON.stringify(valueJson),
  success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
  console.log("Output");
                console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
  }    
    });
```

```css
<?php
include('php/dbconnection.php');
include('validations.php');
include('Samplestates.php');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $head = json_encode($data);
 echo $head;
$id = $data->State_Code;
$name = $data->State_Name;

function doSubmit(){       
    if (checkFormvalues()) 
        {
         $value = ('#addstate').submit();
    }
}
$sql="INSERT INTO m_state1(State_Code, State_Name, Created_By, Created_Date) 
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '1000',now())";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));

?>


Samplestates.php

<?php
function checkFormvalues($statecode, $statename)
{
  $msg = "";
  $isstatecode = false;
  $isstatename = false;
  $ismsg = false;    
                $data = array();
                
  //function to check null
  if(checkNullvalue($statecode))
  {
   //length must be 3
   if(checkCodeLen($statecode))
   {
    //check alphanumeric
    if(checkAlphabets($statecode))
    {
     $isstatecode = true;
    }
    else
    {
     $isstatecode = false;
     $msg .= "Code must be Alphabet";
                                        array_push($data, array("Code" => $msg));
    }
   }
   else
   {
    $isstatecode = false;
    $msg .= "Length must be three charcter";
                                array_push($data, array("Code" => $msg));
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $isstatecode = false;
   $msg .= "Code must be filled out";
                        array_push($data, array("Code" => $msg));
  }
  
                $msg = "";
                
  //function to check null
  if(checkNullvalue($statename))
  {
    //check alphabet
    if(checkAlphabets($statename))
    {
     $isstatename = true;
    }
    else
    {
     $isstatename = false;
     $msg .= "Name must be Alphabet";
                                        array_push($data, array("Name" => $msg));
    }
  }
  else
  {
   $isstatename = false;
   $msg .= "Name must be filled out";
                        array_push($data, array("Name" => $msg));
  }
  
  if(empty($data))
  {
   $ismsg = true;
                        array_push($data, array("Result" => $ismsg));
  }
  else
  {
   $ismsg = false;                        
                        array_push($data, array("Result" => $ismsg));
  }
  
                $outData = array("Response" => $data);
  
                echo json_encode($outData);
                
  return json_encode($outData);
}
?>

validations.php

<?php
//function to check null values
function checkNullvalue($e)
{
 if (empty($e)) 
 {
        return false; 
 }
 else
 {
  return true;
 }
}

function checkCodeLen($value)
{
 if(strlen($value) > 3)
 {
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  return true;
   }   
}

function checkAlphabets($alphabet)
{ 
 if(ctype_alpha($alphabet)) 
 {
     return true;
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
    }
}

function toupper($value)
{
 $upper = strtoupper($value);
 return $upper;
}
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/Addcaste.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/State.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><center>State Entry</center></p>
    <form method="post" class="r" name="addstate" id="addstates" onSubmit="return doSubmit()" action="#">
    <div>
    <table align="center">
  
     <td>State Code</td>
     <td><input type="text" id="statecode" name="statecode" autocomplete="off" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>State Name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="statename" id="statename" autocomplete="off"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" id="submit" /></td>
     <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a few problems in your files, assuming your code is as you've posted it, i'll try and explain a few things.

From what I can understand, you basically want to do this:

1. Fill in a form
2. Submit the form to the server 
3. Validate with php
4. Send a response back to the user that it is valid / invalid

Is that correct?

Comment: thank you for understand this..you are right please give me the way how to include the validation part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably won't help too much if i just tell you how to do it all, you're probably best to spend some time getting familiar with HTML, PHP and Javascript, it seems like you might be missing a few key concepts.

For now, i'd say ignore the javascript part and just focus on the form submission and validation on the server.

## TL;DR

I suggest starting with a video like this: [Build a PHP contact form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtWD_ZH9lnE), that should cover some of the basics of form submission and error checking (validation).

Then start looking at how to combine javascript and PHP with something like this: [Submitting a form with AJAX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrycH6F-ksY)

Hope that helps!